# QGIS 3.10 problems with using the "Reshape features" tool

Tags: qgis, editing

Theoretically, I know how to use the Reshape tool but in practice, I don't know what I am doing wrong.

I am double-clicking on the node, upon it's become active (green color), then creating some new nodes, until the finish. Afterward, I am doing the right-click and everything is gone, or the shape doesn't change the borders as I want when I do the loop selection.

Could someone explain to me how to use this tool properly?

Below the situation:

My proposal new border

[image]

And everything is gone after the right-click, the same as after escape button.

[image: /;]

In turn, when I do something like the loop,

My shape is shrinking, whilst I want to have it extended (towards up according to the image).

[image]

**UPDATE:**

I can use the Vertex tool feature, but it's still far from my goal, as I have to modify all separate nodes one by one.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is not how the reshape tool works. Actually, you do not select any node by double clicking: you just create a duplicated point in your new border, hence the green color (try to double click anywhere outside the polygon, you will get the same green cross).

To expand your polygon, your first and last point must be **inside** the orignal polygon

[image: Before right click]

<sup>Before right click</sup>

[image: After right click]

<sup>After right click</sup>

You can also both expand and shrink the polygon by clicking alternatively inside and outside the polygon.

[image]

[image]